# Qt UDP works well on Android, but IOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, udp

There is a Qt Project about data transmission with UDP。

1， successful build and run on computer, and transplant to Android working well;

2,  To IOS, mobile debugging is ok , sending and receiving data both work;

3,  Out of debugging mode, Open the App on mobile, Receiving data is ok, but sending is failed;

4, Why the same project works well on Android ,but IOS?

Comment: You should really add your code, otherwise all you will get is wild guesses.